# TYPO3 Extension Controller: cache HTTP headers and status along with HTML

Tags: controller, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I created an extension specific “Not found” message to be displayed within the showAction for cases in which a record of the extension has been deleted or hidden. That was quite simple but when it comes to setting the HTTP status to 404, the problem arises that this only works **once** after clearing the caches. Every subsequent call has the status “200 OK”.

Here’s my controller action:

```
public function showAction(\My\Model\Name $model = null)
{
    if (is_null($model)) {
        $this->response->setStatus(404);
        $this->response->sendHeaders();
        $this->view->assign('model', ['notFound'=> 1]);
    } else {
        $this->view->assign('model', $model);
    }
}
```

With a simple condition in the Fluid template I can easily show specific “Record not found” text and hide the HTML for the standard detail view of the record.

Is there any way to cache the status (and headers) sent in the controller action? I know from an earlier problem that the same issue accounts for `$this->response->setHeaders()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function in your controller to handle such Exceptions

```
/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface $request
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ResponseInterface $response
 * @throws \Exception|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception
 */
public function processRequest(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface $request, \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ResponseInterface $response) {

    $aExceptionClasses = array(
        'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception\InvalidSourceException',
        'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Exception\RequiredArgumentMissingException',
        'TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception\TargetNotFoundException',
        'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception'
    );

    try {
        parent::processRequest($request, $response);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {

        $previousException = $e->getPrevious();

        if(in_array(get_class($previousException), $aExceptionClasses) || in_array(get_class($e), $aExceptionClasses)){
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->pageNotFoundAndExit();
        }
        else{
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to do anything else? When I leave my action method as above nothing changes: the first call returns 404, the subsequent ones don’t. When I return to the original method (always assigning the $model to the view) I see default 404 page of the website but curl -I returns a 503 Service Unavailable instead of a 404. Besides the default 404 page isn’t what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Try calling your page with the no cache parameter (http://example.com/index.php?id=123&no_cache=1). You could also try the php header() function to set your status code.

Comment: showAction is typically cached so one solution would be to turn off caching for that pid and/or adding the showAction to your non-cacheable actions array (ext_localconf.php)

Comment: It is a caching issue, indeed, as said in the title of this thread. But of course I can’t turn caching off as the same controller is supposed to show the valid records. I had also tried adding a specific non-cacheable showNotFoundAction() and redirect with `$this->redirect('showNotFound', null, null, null, null, 0, 404);`. But there will be a `meta http-equiv="refresh"` tag _(wrapped in full html within the regular template)_ instead of a header redirect. And finally: I had already tried using the PHP header() function – there’s no difference to using `$this->response->setStatus(404);`

Comment: I don't understand your problem.. with the cache turned off for the page that holds the showAction-Plugin you can check if your parameter is null and set your status to 404. Another method to do that would be the usage of an initializeAction() where you can check if($this->request->getControllerActionName() == 'show') and if the parameter for $model is set, if so, redirect to show, if not, redirect to showNotFound or whatever you intend to do.

Comment: I’m sorry should I be misunderstanding you … but in my comprehension, with turning the cache for the page (?id=123&no_cache=1) off completely, also the final HTML (sub)pages generated by the regular showAction will not be cached. I wouldn’t want that – but please correct me if I’m wrong. And I also mentioned that I tried the redirect() method – and why it isn’t appropriate: An html redirect with `meta http-equiv="refresh"` is not what one should do. Firefox e.g. asks the user to confirm the redirect which isn’t user friendly.

Comment: can you give me a link ?

Comment: This is what I want a visitor to see but with a 404 status sent: https://www.digs-bb.de/index.php?id=11&tx_researchgroups_grouptable[groups]=14&tx_researchgroups_grouptable[action]=show&tx_researchgroups_grouptable[controller]=Groups&cHash=5795631e6661526c9431203d113140da — it is the default showAction that also shows detail views of existing records (which is why it’s being cached). The redirecting to a dedicated action does not work due to the above mentioned reasons. _(it does not work anymore with realurl turned on while it still does in my local version)_